# Need to compare blobs in firebird

Tags: database, blob, firebird

I need to check on the contents of blobs in my databases (yes, plural, but one problem at a time).

In one database, I have about 900 images of potentially varying sizes.  I need to check to see if the versioning system that's built into our application is actually correctly replicating the image data from the previous version to the new version of a record.

How do I compare values en masse so I don't have to pick through each record one at a time and open up the blob using FlameRobin or Firebird Maestro and visually compare these images?

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: add a library that has a md5 http://www.ibphoenix.com/main.nfs?a=ibphoenix&page=ibp_udf_libs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle this in two ways:

1. create some kind of function that returns a unique value for each image, store it in a different column and compare these values
2. get an "external function library" (also called "User Defined Function library") that includes a "blob compare" function: install the library at your server, declare the function in your database and use it.

Answer (score 1):

try to do a hash (like md5) on each bolb and see if they are the same.

```
SELECT
    oldTable.PK
    FROM oldTable
        LEFT OUTER JOIN newTable ON oldTable.PK=newTable.PK
    WHERE MD5(oldTable.blob_column)!=MD5(newTable.blob_column)
```

Comment: Firebird doesn't appear to have an MD5 function according to this: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/SQL_Dialects_Reference/Functions_and_expressions/String_functions  Really good idea though.  Thank you.

Comment: try something like this: http://www.ibphoenix.com/main.nfs?a=ibphoenix&page=ibp_udf_libs